# why is my shader not working in unity HDRP

Tags: unity-game-engine, shader

I have a model in unity, which has the default HDRP lit shader attached to it.

The problem is that the shader displays as incredibly dark, to the point where it may as well be black, unless the camera is right next to the model, in which case it is normal brightness, and the rest of the scene is very bright. This error only occurs in baked directional light mode, but i want to keep it in baked mode, not realtime. Also, if i turn the intensity up on the directional light it makes the rest of the scene way too bright. [image: this is the image where the rest of the scene is really bright.] [image: this is the image of the scene being normal brightness and the character being way too dark to see.]

Comment: Please give a picture of the shader code in shader editor.

Comment: It is the default HDRP lit shader, but sure: https://pastebin.com/KtFSgWaA